# Jenkins Jobs are not loading while starting it from CLI

Tags: jenkins

I have setup a lot of jobs while Jenkins is running as windows service.When i try to start Jenkins from command line , none of the jobs are showing up.

Can some one let me know how to make sure all jobs are loaded when i start Jenkins from CLI on windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the same Jenkins home directory when you run it from CLI.

You can use JENKINS_HOME variable to control that:

```
set JENKINS_HOME=C:/myJenkins
java -jar jenkins.war
```